# define aliases for shell-command?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is there a way to define aliases so that `shell-command` can recognize them? `shell` recognizes those defined in .emacs.d/init_bash.sh; is it possible to make `shell-command` aware of these also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read in `simple.el` in `shell-command` code :

```
    ;; We do not use -f for csh; we will not support broken use of
    ;; .cshrcs.  Even the BSD csh manual says to use
    ;; "if ($?prompt) exit" before things which are not useful
    ;; non-interactively.  Besides, if someone wants their other
    ;; aliases for shell commands then they can still have them.
    (call-process shell-file-name nil
          (if error-file
              (list t error-file)
            t)
          nil shell-command-switch command)
```

The `nil` after `shell-file-name` indicates that emacs don't send an input file to the process. Thus, you should check the value of `shell-file-name` to determine if it's a process that read implicit .rc files.

Comment: My shell-file-name is "bin/bash" but I'm still not sure how to interpret these instructions...?

Comment: man bash to know exactly what is done when bash process starts.

Comment: Thanks - I created a link file so that /bin/bash can use it.

Comment: Can you clarify the /bin/bash case?  Pointing to man bash isn't too helpful.

Comment: Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224909/is-there-a-way-to-get-my-emacs-to-recognize-my-bash-aliases-and-custom-functions