# Is there a way to get my emacs to recognize my bash aliases and custom functions when I run a shell command?

Tags: bash, shell, emacs, environment-variables

In my shell environment I have aliases and custom functions. When I am in an instance of emacs (I always use `emacs -nw`) and I execute a shell command (`M-!`) I cannot use them. This makes sense since I imagine it launches it's own subshell to do these... but is there a way (maybe in my `.emacs`) to get this to work? Perhaps even if it involved sourcing an environment by default before executing any shell command given?

Comment: It's starting in non-login mode, you'll have to find where to change the command to run to start the shell and add `-l`.  I use vim so I'm not sure where emacs hides this.

Comment: The problem is not login but interactive. The execute subcommand shell is non interactive (as shown by running `M-x ! tty -s` which gives a code of 1).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emacs compilation mode wont see bash alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10946219/emacs-compilation-mode-wont-see-bash-alias)

Comment: I had this issue as well. However, due to the peculiarities of `M-&` and its counterpart in Dired, I just gave up and put my alias into `.zshenv` instead. [See my answer on this question for more details.](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/53554/10761)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Below are my comments about what I think was a related question:

I think both <kbd>M-x</kbd> **shell-command** and <kbd>M-x</kbd> **compile** execute commands in an inferior shell via call-process. Try the following in your .emacs (or just evaluate):

```el
(setq shell-file-name "bash")
(setq shell-command-switch "-ic")
```

I notice that after evaluation of the above, .bashrc aliases are picked up for use by both <kbd>M-x</kbd> shell-command and <kbd>M-x</kbd> compile, i.e

<kbd>M-x</kbd> compile <kbd>RET</kbd> **your_alias** <kbd>RET</kbd>

should then work.

My environment: Emacs 24.1 (pretest rc1), OSX 10.7.3

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10958134/1046267)

Comment: This worked beautifully! Thanks, what does the "-ic" part do? Is it for interactive?

Comment: @PalaceChan: `-i` is for interactive, and `-c` tells bash to read whatever commands follow (so whatever Emacs uses in it's shell call).

Comment: @PalaceChan given your next question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918614/how-to-run-shell-commands-in-emacs-on-ubuntu-while-avoiding-a-bash-job-control-e?lq=1 ) which asks why this gives you an error how did it work beautifully?

Comment: (Emacs 24.4.1 in Terminator) This is pretty much working for me but I get messages before output:   bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1):   Inappropriate ioctl for device bash: no job control in this shell

Comment: This doesn't work - I'm running emacs 26.1, bash 4.4

Comment: Worked. But got warnings `bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell`

Comment: Works for me with `GNU Emacs 27.1`, `zsh 5.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin20.0)` (**not**  changing `shell-file-name`, just `shell-command-switch`)

Comment: Worked for me and changed my life!, a bit, running Aquamacs 3.5 -> GNU Emacs 25.3.50.

Answer (score 3):

We need to enable alias expansion in non-interactive shells, preferably only when they are called from emacs (to avoid causing subtle differences when we run other shells).  What worked for me was to create two files: ~/.alias has all my aliases, e.g.

```
alias python python27
```

and ~/.aliasExpand has

```
source ~/.alias
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

I also, of course, replaced all my aliases in .bashrc with

```
source ~/.alias
```

Finally, I added this to my .emacs:

```
(setenv "BASH_ENV" "~/.aliasExpand")
```

I tried Keith Flower's solution (of making shells interactive), and I got

> bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
>   bash: no job control in this shell

Note that I got this through Glenn Jackman's and Nicholas Dudebout's hints.

If you are willing to risk having all your shells have alias expansion and you don't mind running all your .bashrc for every emacs shell, you can simplify this to adding

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

to your .bashrc and

```
(setenv "BASH_ENV" "~/.bashrc")
```

to your .emacs

Comment: Thanks for the answer. BTW, I think you can just use `(setenv "BASH_ENV" (expand-file-name "~/.bashrc"))` or `(setenv "BASH_ENV" (substitute-in-file-name "$HOME/.bashrc"))`, then `shopt` won't be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Have a read through http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files

For non-interactive shells, the only file that is sourced is the value of the BASH_ENV environment variable. You invoke emacs like `BASH_ENV=~/.bashrc emacs` **if** emacs will use bash for shell commands -- some programs specifically use "/bin/sh"

Comment: It seems that you will also have to enable the alias mechanism by using `shopt -s expand_aliases`. This is not enabled in a non interactive shell by default.

Answer (score 2):

To get `shell-command` to read `~/.bashrc` before executing the command per the technique described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/12228646/8869495, without potential side effects due to `$BASH_ENV` being defined for your entire Emacs session, try this in your `~/.emacs.d/init.el` (or `.emacs`) file:

```
;; I want M-! (shell-command) to pick up my aliases and so run .bashrc:
(setq shell-file-name "bash-for-emacs.sh")  ; Does this: BASH_ENV="~/.bashrc" exec bash "$@"
(setq shell-command-switch "-c")
```

As described by the comment in the second line, also install (in your `$PATH`) a script named `bash-for-emacs.sh` that contains:

```
#!/bin/bash

BASH_ENV="~/.bashrc" exec bash "$@"
```

Note that your `~/.bashrc` might need to be changed to define non-interactive aliases even when `[ -z "$PS1" ]` is true (which indicates a non-interactive shell). That's the approach I'm taking for my own environment (such as it is), which is at https://github.com/jcburley/UnixHome.

Also, this assumes you want to use Bash as your Emacs-spawned shell, as I do.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `shell-command-switch` directly will substantially make `shell-command` much more sluggish (if you use many `(ba|z)sh` plugins), which is invoked by various non-interactive functions like `shell-command-to-string`, `eshell-remote-command`,... and numerous calls of it from other functions, all of which won't ever need `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`

For example, on my machine (and likely yours, too):

```lisp
(benchmark-elapse (let ((shell-command-switch "-c")) (shell-command "")))
0.005170422
(benchmark-elapse (let ((shell-command-switch "-ic")) (shell-command "")))
0.242628824
;; Empty ~/.zshrc: 0.168341049
```

Therefore, we should opt find a way to use the interactive shell only when `shell-command` is called interactively

```lisp
;;;###autoload
(defun my-shell-command-interactive-a (fn &rest args)
  "Use interactive shell for `shell-command' when invoked interactively.
Setting the \"-i\" switch all the time will significantly slow
down `shell-command' because there may too many files to source."
  (let ((shell-command-switch (if (called-interactively-p 'interactive)
                                  ;; Replace the first "-"
                                  (replace-regexp-in-string
                                   "\\(-\\).*\\'"
                                   "-i"
                                   shell-command-switch
                                   nil
                                   nil
                                   1)
                                shell-command-switch)))
    (apply fn args)))

(dolist (cmd '(shell-command async-shell-command)) 
   (advice-add cmd :around #'my-shell-command-interactive-a))
```

Answer (score -4):

Put the aliases and functions in `.bashrc`, not `.bash_profile`. The latter is only executed in login shells, the former is in all shells.

Comment: .bashrc is sourced for *interactive* shells, not *all* shells: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files

Comment: @Barmar, putting the aliases in `.bashrc` does not change a thing.