# How can I resolve a sed invalid reference error when trying to use bash to overwrite Emacs eshell alias list?

Tags: bash, sed, emacs, alias, eshell

I'm trying to get Emacs eshell to use the same alias' as bash.

I tried following the wisdom in the top comment from Stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224909/is-there-a-way-to-get-my-emacs-to-recognize-my-bash-aliases-and-custom-functions), which was to add these two lines to the .emacs profile:

```
(setq shell-file-name "bash")
(setq shell-command-switch "-ic")
```

but nothing happened.

Then I tried this wiki option [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EshellAlias#toc9). Which is to have the bash alias script overwrite the emacs eshell alias file whenever a new terminal opens:

```
alias | sed -E "s/^alias ([^=]+)='(.*)'$/alias \1 \2 \$*/g; s/'\\\''/'/g;" >~/.emacs.d/eshell/alias
```

However, this one results in an error when I open a new terminal (note that running it with a capital -E doesn't work for me):

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 42: invalid reference \2 on 's' commands' RHS.
```

Would anyone know how to go about resolving this sed error? I realize the wiki option specifically points to using .bashrc - admittedly, I don't know how this is different from the ~/.alias file I've been using.

For example, I have a .alias file like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
alias episas="nice -19 perl $EPI/analysis/scripts/episas ";

 alias | sed -e "s/^alias ([^=]+)='(.*)'$/alias \1 \2 \$*/g; s/'\\\''/'/g;" >~/.emacs.d/eshell/alias
```

and I want my /.emacs.d/eshell/alias file to have the same alias for episas.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: it'd help if you post few sample lines from output of `alias` and show expected output for those lines..

Comment: or try to find a minimal example to reproduce the error.. I don't see an error when I try this: `echo "alias c='clear'" | sed -E "s/^alias ([^=]+)='(.*)'$/alias \1 \2 \$*/g; s/'\\\''/'/g;"`

Comment: Are you sure it calls the same `sed`? Try specifying the full path.

Comment: Thanks Sundeep, I added an example to clarify what I'm asking for. My alias' list is really simple in the bash .alias file, and I want my Emacs eshell alias list to have the same items.

Comment: Thanks choroba - I'm not sure how to determine which sed it uses. Admittedly new to sed, but when I use which sed, I get: /usr/bin/sed and changing it to use the full path doesn't resolve it.

Comment: the two given lines won't match any of the two sed commands.. so not a good sample... anyway, here's another thing you can try (use a copy of alias file) ... delete lines from the copy file until you see the error.. that will narrow down cause of error

Comment: The `-E` just provides syntactic sugar try `sed -e "s/^alias \([^=][^=]*\)='\(.*\)'$/alias \1 \2 \$*/g; s/'\\\''/'/g;" file`

Comment: Thank you @potong! That worked!